# Integrable or antiderivative

Tags: integration

Is there any difference between a function being integrable (since there are many ways to define whether a function is integrable, let's stick to Riemann integration.) and it's antiderivative existing? The antiderivative need not be any simple/analytic function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. For instance, the function $f(0) = 1$, $f(x) = 0$ for $x \ne 0$ is integrable in any interval, but has no antiderivative.

Comment: it's antiderivative is any constant

Comment: @exploringnet, the derivative of a constant is $0$, so that can't be an antiderivative of $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the discussion, if a function has an antiderivative, is it integrable?  This depends on how you define the integration

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterras_function

This function is not Riemannian integrable even though it is bounded and antiderivative exists everywhere.  I wonder, does existence of an antiderivative imply Lebesgue integrability?