# Integral vs antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I have a similar question to this one: [Integrable or antiderivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335751/integrable-or-antiderivative).

If a function has an antiderivative, does the difference of values of the antiderivative on the endpoints of an interval always equal the function's integral (Riemann, Cauchy, Lebesgue) over that interval?

Comment: Yes, if the function is integrable. There are derivatives that are not Riemann integrable, or even Lebesgue integrable. If we use the Henstock-Kurzweil integral, then yes, this holds for all derivatives.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a function whose antiderivative behaves as I explained above?

Comment: Not always here is an example [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902537/to-be-integrable-a-function-must-be-bounded-yet-int-1-x3-dx-1-2x2)