# Fundamental theorem of calculus necessary assumption

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

The fundamental theorem of calculus [is stated as follows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part):

Let $f$ and $F$ be real-valued functions defined on a closed interval $[a, b]$ such that the derivative of $F$ is $f$. That is, $f$ and $F$ are functions such that for all $x \in [a, b]$,

$F'(x) = f(x)$

If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ then

$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a)$

My question is: is it necessary to say ''if $f$ is Riemann integrable''? It seems to me that if $f$ is the derivative of a function $F$ then it must be Riemann integrable.

> Is there an example of $f$ and $F$ such that $F'=f$ and $f$ is not
>   Riemann integrable?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353452/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-riemann-integrability

Comment: I tried to make the question clearer.

Comment: Alex, how does your comment relate to my question? The linked thread does not seem to mention if $f$ is the derivative of a function then...

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/335792/) mentions [Volterra's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterras_function). Its derivative is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Note that every derivative is integrable if you consider the _generalized Riemann integral_.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Thank you for your comment. It is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question at the end of your post:

> Is there an example of $f$ and $F$ such that $F'=f$ and $f$ is not
>   Riemann integrable?

---

Quote from *van Rooij, Schikhof: A Second Course on Real Functions*, [p.4](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA4):

> (8) *A function that has an antiderivative but is not Riemann integrable.*
>   The function $h$ defined by
>   $$h(x):=
>   \begin{cases}
>     2x\sin x^{-2}-2x^{-1}\cos x^{-2} & \text{if }x\in(0,1], \\
>     0 & \text{if }x=0.
>   \end{cases}
> $$
>   is unbounded, hence certainly not Riemann integrable. But it is the derivative of $H$, where
>   $$H(x):=
>   \begin{cases}
>     x^2\sin x^{-2} & \text{if }x\in(0,1], \\
>     0 & \text{if }x=0.
>   \end{cases}
> $$

---

If you prefer an example which is bounded, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/335792/) mentions [Volterra's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterras_function). Its derivative is not Riemann integrable.